# how to count the number of time a specific string is repeated in a set of files and get the names of the files using python

Tags: python

I have 100 files in a folder and I want to list the name of files where there is a string "student" in the file's contents, and to count the number of times this string is repeated in each file.

Desired output:

```
file1.txt :6
file3.txt :4
file5.txt :2
```

Code so far:

```
counter = 0
for file in os.listdir("/home/joe/Desktop/eclipse/test/src"):
    if "student" in file.read():
        print (file)
        counter += 1
print (counter + " files found.")
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: please how to use grep?

Comment: thanks for your prompt reponse i'm getting this error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) utility.

```
joe@linuxbox ~/Desktop/eclipse/test/src $ grep -c "student" *.txt
file1.txt:6
file2.txt:0
file3.txt:4
file4.txt:0
file5.txt:2
```

The `-c` or `--count` option does exactly what you want: it prints the file name and the number of matches in the file, including `0` if the search pattern is not found.

Comment: thanks @MattDMo ,it works fine,now i'm going to customize it in order to get only files having value 1 and remove those having 0 as value...thanks

Comment: ,thanks for advise and sorry for delay .